# The hat function

Tags: functions

A hat function in 2D Cartesian is defined as

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x, & x\geq 0\\
-x, & x<0
\end{cases}$$

Could any one help me how the hat function is defined in 3D Cartesian.

Note, I have a feeling the answer could be a pyramid.

Comment: I don't think there is a unique or universally accepted version of your function in higher dimensions.  (Nor have I heard it called "hat," since it is simply absolute value.)  One can easily create candidate functions by $f(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$, to take just one example.

Comment: First off, the definition of the hat function with which I am familiar is $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1-|x| & x \in [-1,1] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$  What you have written is the absolute value function (except that you have not defined it at zero).  Beyond that, for what purpose are you seeking a generalization?  That is going to influence the correct choice of a generalization (of which there are several that come to mind).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork ,thanks. Maybe I reframe my question. The hat function has well known derivatives in 2D Cartesian, namely +1 and -1 dependin on x. Now do we have any 3D object with derivatives +1 and -1.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for the correction. Yes it is absolute value function not defined at zero. I work in polar. And in polar tangents to absolute value function are the same with Cartesian. I want such 3D object to have the same tangents in 3D Cartesian and spherical system.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hgkmaxn7rq

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks great elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

For a real number $x$ you have the absolute value $|x|$ as defined by you. The geometric meaning of $|x|$ is the distance of $x$ to the origin.

In higher dimension, there are far more possibilities to define the *distance* of a point to the origin. For example, for all $p\in[1,\infty]$ there is the $p$-norm $\|~\cdot~\|_p$ defined for a vector $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ by
$$
\|x\|_p=\begin{cases}
\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k| & p=1\\
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|^p\right)^{\frac1p} & p\in(1,\infty)\\
\max\{|x_1|,\ldots,|x_n|\} & p=\infty
\end{cases}.
$$
The shade of the function $f_p:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, defined by $f_p(x)=\|x\|_p$ depends on $p$.

If you are interested in the classical hat function, then I have to agree with the comments. Normally you consider 
$$
f(x)=\max\{0,1-|x|\}.
$$
Using this, you can also get different hat functions for higher dimension by
$$
f_p(x)=\max\{0,1-\|x\|_p\}.
$$
The form depends again on $p$. For $p=1$ and $p=\infty$, you get pyramids while $p=2$ has a circle as its support.

Comment: Thanks. Let me please realise which one sweets my need.

Comment: Why separating to cases the p-norm? $p=1$ is exactly like the others, and $p=\infty$ is taking the limit

Comment: I agree that $p=1$ and $p\in(1,\infty)$ can be described in one formula. But $p=\infty$ as "taking the limit" is a bit fishy. However, the cases $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ are in fact a bit special. Nevertheless, my arguments do not depend on whether I combine all cases into one formula or I write it with cases like I did.